# jQuery code works in jsFiddle, but not on my site

Tags: jquery

I've written a script for a login that creates a username by concatenating first + last name (on blur), removing whitespaces and removing special characters.

Everything works fine in jsFiddle, but not on my site - I get 3 times error '$str' is not defined - so my guess is that the replace function on line 5 + 10 isn't fired.

Any ideas what's wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/Hxjyy/2/

The code:

```
jQuery().ready(function() {
    jQuery('#firstname').blur(function() {
        var $login = jQuery('#firstname').val().toLowerCase()+jQuery('#firstname').val().toLowerCase();
        $login = $login.replace(/\s/g, "");  
        $login = replaceChars($login);
        jQuery("#login").val($login);
    });
    jQuery('#lastname').blur(function() {
        var $login = jQuery('#firstname').val().toLowerCase()+jQuery('#lastname').val().toLowerCase();
        $login = $login.replace(/\s/g, "");  
        $login = replaceChars ($login);
        jQuery("#login").val($login);
    });

    function replaceChars($str)
        {
        var charMap = {
            é:'e',è:'e',ë:'e',ê:'e',à:'a',
            ç:'c',á:'a',ö:'o'
        };
        var str_array = $str.split('');

        for( var i = 0, len = str_array.length; i < len; i++ ) {
            str_array[ i ] = charMap[ str_array[ i ] ] || str_array[ i ];
        }
        $str= str_array.join('');
        return($str);
    }
});
```

Comment: The link you posted isn't the same code as what you've posted.

Comment: Your code in jsfiddle does not work...

Comment: woops - something went wrong there - just a moment...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Hxjyy/2/ is the correct link...

Comment: `jQuery().ready(` is incorrect, use `jQuery(` or `jQuery(document).ready(`. Besides that, the callback function receives the jQuery object as its first argument so you can (and should!) use `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ ... })` and then use the `$` shortcut inside.

Comment: Additionally you **should not** prefix your variables with `$`! While it's kind of common to use it for jQuery objects - especially `$this`, using it for all variables is just ugly and serves no proper purpose.

Comment: @ThiefMaster thanks for the tips - i'm pretty new to jQuery. As for the `$` shortcut: where do I use it inside?

Comment: Are you mixing other javascripts on your page with jQuery?

Comment: @Rumplin Yes - it's integrated in a Wordpress site - full source code on http://pastebin.com/XAJiK9XC

Comment: @ptriek: You use it instead of `jQuery`. Inside the function, `$ === jQuery`. Actually, the same thing applies outside, unless you used `$.noConflict()`.

Comment: I just discovered that the problem was caused by the special characters in the replaceChars function - if I replace them with the Javascript entities like \u00EB it works fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that the problem was caused by the special characters in the replaceChars function - if I replace them with the Javascript entities like \u00EB it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - Ok, now it makes more sense, have you tried taking the function outside (and before) $(document).ready()? I sometimes have problem with that. And you should write `jQuery(document).ready()`

```
      function replaceChars($str)
      {
        var charMap = {
            é:'e',è:'e',ë:'e',ê:'e',à:'a',
            ç:'c',á:'a',ö:'o'
        };
        var str_array = $str.split('');

        for( var i = 0, len = str_array.length; i < len; i++ ) {
            str_array[ i ] = charMap[ str_array[ i ] ] || str_array[ i ];
        }
        $str= str_array.join('');
        return($str);
      }


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#firstname').blur(function() {
        var $login = jQuery('#firstname').val().toLowerCase()+jQuery('#firstname').val().toLowerCase();
        $login = $login.replace(/\s/g, "");  
        $login = replaceChars($login);
        jQuery("#login").val($login);
    });
    jQuery('#lastname').blur(function() {
        var $login = jQuery('#firstname').val().toLowerCase()+jQuery('#lastname').val().toLowerCase();
        $login = $login.replace(/\s/g, "");  
        $login = replaceChars ($login);
        jQuery("#login").val($login);
    });

});
```

Comment: sorry, posted the wrong link - http://jsfiddle.net/Hxjyy/2/ is the correct one...

Comment: this works in jsfiddler, but gives error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL' on my site...

Comment: jQuery(document).ready == $(document).ready if $ is not defined otherwise

Comment: @Rumplin in the example "document" is omitted